# PG::ConnectionBad error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, heroku

I quit my `rails s` and went to restart it quickly and all of a sudden I am getting this weird error:

```
2016-11-11 18:59:59 -0500: Rack app error handling request { GET /profiles }
#<PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
>
```

I did some research but nothing helps me properly.

I tried looking for a `.pid` file in my `/usr/local/var/postgres/` folder, because some answers suggested I deleted, but my folder doesn't have that.

I even saw something about checking my `server.log` and I didn't have that in that folder either.

Eventually I stumbled across this command, which I ran successfully:

```
$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
server starting
```

However, that doesn't solve my issue. What it does do though is create a `server.log` file for me.

That file has the following contents:

```
LOG:  skipping missing configuration file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.auto.conf"
FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.3, which is not compatible with this version 9.4.4.
```

I am running the Postgres App from Heroku on macOS Sierra.

What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that this is a fix, but I restarted my machine and everything works like normal.

If someone has a more complete answer, that would be good.